# Shell command to copy and paste specific text from one file to another

Tags: perl, shell, awk

Shell command to copy and paste specific text from one file to another?

**InputFile**

```
DIRECTOR> TM_6000 Source Load Summary.
DIRECTOR> CIN_1740 Table: [SQ_BOX_CONTROL] (Instance Name: [SQ_BOX_CONTROL])
Output Rows [1], Affected Rows [1], Applied Rows [1345], Rejected Rows [0]
DIRECTOR> TM_6001 Target Load Summary.
DIRECTOR> CIN_1740 Table: [JBOX_CONTROL] (Instance Name: [JBOX_CONTROL])
Output Rows [1], Affected Rows [1], Applied Rows [1340], Rejected Rows [0]
DIRECTOR> TM_6023
===================================================

DIRECTOR> TM_6020 Session [s_m_CONTROL] completed at [Tue Sep 15 02:49:12 2015].
```

**Need Output in the below format**

```
Session : s_m_CONTROL
Source : 1345
Target : 1340
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. First, I don't think that you really mean *copy and paste*, since this term doesn't make much sense here, but *extract information* from a text file. Secondly, I don't understand under what conditions you associate 1345 to *Source* and 1340 to *Target*, but in general, your questions boils down to extract certain information from a text file. If you really **want** to use shell programming only, you need to specify which shell you want to use (or if any shell would be fine), because the capabilities in string handling vary a lot between different shells.

Comment: However, I personally would not program this in shell language, but use a language which is better suited for text processing, such as *awk*, *Ruby* or *Perl* - to mention just a few. In any case, show first what you have already tried, so that we have a base for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You give no useful information about how you want to extract data from your input. So this code is a complete guess, but it does give the output you asked for from your given input. And it will be reasonably simple to change it to deal with other extraction requirements.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %session;

while (<>) {
  if (/Applied Rows \[(\d+)]/) {
     if (exists $session{Source}) {
       $session{Target} = $1;
     } else {
       $session{Source} = $1;
     }
  }
  if (/Session \[(\w+)]/) {
    $session{Session} = $1;
  }
}

for (qw[Session Source Target]) {
  say "$_ : $session{$_}";
}
```

It is written as a Unix filter - it reads from STDIN and writes to STDOUT. So if your input data is in a one file and you want the output in another file, you would call it like this:

```
$ ./session_extract < some_input_file > some_output_file
```

But it also works if your input is the output from some other process and you want the output written to STDOUT.

```
$ some_other_process | ./session_extract
```

(Many other options are availbable Unix I/O redirection is incredibly flexible.)

Answer (score 0):

Doing this kind of operation would be the way to go.

```
#! /bin/bash

# Extract session val
session=$(echo $file | grep "Session" | cut -d"[" -f2 | cut -d"]" -f1)
# ...
```

Next problem would be: The source ou output lines have no differences... Have to find a way around like, finding first occurence? Then second?